# Including External Factories in AngularJs Modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to create a factory to abstract my `$http` calls.  I would like to use this factory in multiple modules, but I only wish to maintain one copy of the file.

I see that I am doing something similar with `kendo.directives`:

```
angular.module('createPolicy', ['kendo.directives'])
    .controller('CreatePolicyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

How can I create my factory such that I can simply include it like `kendo.directives` after I include the `.js` source?

For example:

```
angular.module('createPolicy', ['kendo.directives', 'myPolicyService'])
    .controller('CreatePolicyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

How would I have to construct the factory to be able to use it like that?

**Edit:** I have the following in angular-factories.js:

```
var policyService = angular.module("PolicyService", []);
policyService.factory('PolicyService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getFoos: function () {
            //return the promise directly.
            return $http.get('/foos')
                      .then(function (result) {
                          //resolve the promise as the data
                          return result.data;
                      });
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in a different file, I try to use it like so:

```
angular.module('createPolicy', ['kendo.directives', 'PolicyService'])
    .controller('CreatePolicyController', ['$scope', function ($scope, policyService) {
        $scope.editPolicy = true;
        $scope.packages = [];

        console.log(policyService.getFoos());
```

But, I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFoos' of undefined

I am including the files like this (in ASP.NET MVC):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryplugins").Include(
    "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-factories.js",
    "~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would define your own module.

```
var specialHttpModule = angular.module("specialHttpModule", []);
specialHttpModule.service("someSpecialService", someSpecialService);
```

This would be in the `.js` file for this module.  Then, you would be able to include it as a dependency or retrieve it with `angular.module("specialHttpModule");`  To add it to your `createPolicy` module you need to add the module name to the list of dependencies:

```
angular.module('createPolicy', ['kendo.directives', 'specialHttpModule'])
```

Then all the services, directives and controllers declared in `specialHttpModule` will be available in your module to inject:

```
.controller('CreatePolicyController', ['$scope', 'someSpecialService',
    function ($scope, someSpecialService) {
```

Comment: How would I "attach" the module in my controller which already has a module defined (createPolicy module and CreatePolicyController)?

Comment: @user1477388 I don't understand; can you show me your code?

Comment: I updated the question with some more code - I just want to include my factory on the existing module, similar to how the `kendo.directives` are included.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Nice, that gets me closer.  However, I am getting an error.  Could you please see the update to my question and let me know if you know what may be the culprit?

Comment: @user1477388 you are not injecting `PolicyService` into the controller.

Comment: It should be .controller('CreatePolicyController', ['$scope', 'PolicyService', function ($scope, PolicyService), it's also case sensitive...

Comment: Sorry, I see that now.  However, it is giving me another error:  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n%20%3C-%20PolicyService (Unknown provider)

Comment: @user1477388 can you show us an SSCCE?  This should be working if you are doing it correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ndmstacg/ -- you possibly have something misspelled, or you're doing something in the wrong order or using the wrong name, etc.

Comment: The problem was I was saying `.factory` instead of `.service`.  Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `service` or `factory` use the `Provider` version of same with `get` property on object returned and configure same provider in multiple modules in the `config` section

**Factory:**

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .factory('myService', function() {
 return {
     'username': 'auser',
     'url': ''
      'setUrl': function(inputUrl){
          this.url = inputUrl;
      }
 }
})
```

**Equivalent Provider:**

```
var appProvider = angular.module('appProvider', []);
    appProvider.provider('myService', {
        $get: function() {
          return {
             'username': 'auser',
             'url': ''
             'setUrl': function(inputUrl){
                 this.url = inputUrl;
              }
          }
        }
     });
```

**Configuring the provider in multiple modules:**

**Module 1:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['appProvider'])
 .config(function(myServiceProvider) {
     myServiceProvider
         .setUrl("stackoverflow.com");
});
```

**Module 2:**

```
angular.module('secondApp', ['appProvider'])
 .config(function(myServiceProvider) {
     myServiceProvider
         .setUrl("google.com");
});
```

Comment: Providers are still defined per-module.  Module 2 would not have access to myServiceProvider if it were only defined in Module 1.

Comment: Module2 will be able to access myServiceProvider by creating a separate module for providers and loading that as dependencies on both Module1 and Module2. Changed the above code for same to have an appProvider module for providers which can be used in any other modules as dependency to have the specific provider(in this case myServiceProvider)